# Various method of calling a function automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have heard of some method of calling a function automatically in javascript when a page loads.This question is to know which method is best over all others.

**If your method is different from all others' then please mention your method here whether it is good or bad.**

Comment: What exactly is your question ? Yes there is the unload function in which you can you whatever you want.

Comment: You should list the options you want to see the difference. Basically it boils down to the basic decision: load event or ready event.

Comment: I use jQuery `$();` function; tooooo common

Answer (score 4):

Your options are:

1. Just put a `script` tag at the end of the page and put your function call there. If it's right before (or after) the closing `</body>` tag, all of the DOM elements above it are there and ready to be manipulated ([reference](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)). Images and other resources may or may not yet be loaded. Barring some specific reason you need to do something else, this is your best bet, [frequently recommended](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).
2. Using the `window` `load` event, which you can hook via `addEventListener` on standard browsers or `attachEvent` on older versions of IE. That happens **very** late in the cycle, after all images and other resources are loaded. (You can also hook it using the old-fashioned `onload` attribute on the `body` tag, but I don't recommend it.)
3. On standard browsers, there's a [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded) that fires when the DOM is ready but earlier than `window` `load`. You hook it via `addEventListener`.
4. Most JavaScript libraries provide some kind of "when the DOM is ready" event that you can hook into. jQuery uses the `ready(yourFunction)` function, Prototype uses `document.observe("dom:loaded", yourFunction)`, etc.

Comment: @AnkitGautam: Because it requires that you mix your code in with your markup, and only one bit of code can "hook" it. Using `addEventListener` / `attachEvent`, as many listeners as are needed for the event can be added.